# custom mysqli database class returning data it shouldn't

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating a MySQLi database class for my own personal use to clean up the prepared statements usage within functions on my own code and for my own learning and experience. However I have run into a complication when running 2 or more queries on a single page.

Using my basic SELECT function I can run 2 queries as such:

```
$data = $db->SELECT("SELECT * FROM hist WHERE id = ?", array('i', 2));
$data2 = $db->SELECT("SELECT * FROM hist WHERE id = ?", array('i', 3));
```

and as seen, these two queries are saved to separate variables.

Doing a `var_dump` on `$data` shows me the correct result, for `id=2`:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["value"]=>
    float(51.4)
  }
}
```

However doing a `var_dump` on `$data2` shows me the data for `id=2` and `id=3` which sort of suggests the results are concatenating with each other?

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["value"]=>
    float(51.4)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["value"]=>
    float(476)
  }
}
```

What could be causing this and how could this be fixed? Do I have to initiate a new instance of the class per query? I tried to unset the resulting data at the end of the function but this didn't seem to help.

My SELECT function from my class:

```
public function SELECT($sql, $args=null) {
    if ($stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql)) {
        if(isset($args)) {
            $method = new ReflectionMethod('mysqli_stmt', 'bind_param'); 
            $method->invokeArgs($stmt, $this->refValues($args));
        }
        if(!$stmt->execute()) {
            array_push($this->err, 'execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        }           
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        if (count($result) >= 1) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                array_push($this->rs, $row);
            }
        } 
        else {
            array_push($this->rs, "No data has been returned.");
        }
    }
    else {
        array_push($this->err, 'prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($this->link->error));
    }

    if(!empty($this->err)) {
        if($this->debug) {
            return $this->err;
        }
    }
    else {
        return $this->rs;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    unset($this->err);
    unset($this->rs);
}
```

Comment: *Doing a var_dump on $data2 shows me the data from both $data and $data2*: that's not clear... At first glance, I'd say it's just not possible... So, I certainly misunderstand this sentence... What are `$data` and `$data2` supposed to contain? What does your table contains?

Comment: @Arcesilas If i var_dump `$data` i get 1 result, for `id=2` as expected. If i `var_dump` on `$data2` i get 2 results, 1 for `id=2` and 1 for `id=3` which is not expected. It seems to be 'adding' the two results together query after query.  I am sure the database is correct, especially since my ID is a pk and of course can only return 1 result if its a pk.

Comment: @Arcesilas I have edited my question - I hope this is clearer?

Comment: First, we don't know what's in your DB. Second, we don't know with which parameters you execute your queries. Third, there are methods you use but don't show (like `refValues()`). Conclusion: it's not easy to help... :)

Comment: What's the point of that: `$method = new ReflectionMethod('mysqli_stmt', 'bind_param');`? Why not just call `$stmt->bind_param()`?

Comment: @Arcesilas `$method = new ReflectionMethod('mysqli_stmt', 'bind_param');` is used to dynamically bind params based on an array. If i used `$stmt->bind_param()` it would need to be hard coded every time. `refValues()` allows for the use of this method and if this was the issue then bind_param would fail and no query would execute. The database is fine.. The issue lies around the returning of `$this->rs` but im not sure what the issue is exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is this part.

```
if(!empty($this->err)) {
    if($this->debug) {
        return $this->err;
    }
}
else {
    return $this->rs;
}
$stmt->close();
unset($this->err);
unset($this->rs);
```

You are returning either `$this->rs` or `$this->err` so `unset()` never executes or more precisely as Arcesilas said, it unsets variables only if there is error and debugging is off.

Store result in temp variable and return result.

```
$stmt->close();
if(!empty($this->err)) {
    $result = $this-err;
    unset($this-err);
    if($this->debug) {
        return $result;
    }
}
else {
    $result = $this->rs;
    unset($this->rs);
    return $result;
}
```

You could refactor this with cleaner code but you get the idea.

Easier alternative is to just move

```
unset($this->err);
unset($this->rs);
```

to the top of function `SELECT`.

Comment: They are executed if there is an error an debug is off.

Comment: What would the fix be? how can I unset it after return, or reset the rs variable upon a new use of the class?

Comment: @Arcesilas Yes, apart from that.

Comment: Store the values in a temporary variable, unset, return the temporary variable.

Comment: I had to add in a final re-declaration of the arrays rs/err but otherwise it worked great. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt Yeah another alternative is to just unset both `$this->err` and `$this->rs` at the beginning of function `SELECT`.

Comment: @TheDrot I am using global variables in the class `class db { protected $rs = array(); ...}` Out of interest, how come it isn't resetting at the beginning there?

Comment: @Matt Class properties are 'reset' only when you instantiate the class. If you call class methods multiple times on same instance, properties keep their values unless you specifically set/unset them in methods. And since in your code you are exiting method before unsetting, result stays in your property and gets concatenated next time you call same method.

Comment: @TheDrot ah okay that makes sense. Thanks for that :).